# Remove key from a Json inside a JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I have JsonObject like below

```
{"status":"ACTIVE","accounts":{"email":"email@gmail.com","name":"Test"}}
```

How can I remove Json key "email" and its value from the JsonObject by using something like `jsonObj.remove("email")` in java

JsonObj.removev working for me if I need to remove status key `jsonObj.remove("status")`

Update

Some more background, 
This is for mainly testing a rest end point. In my test I created java object matching to payload with Builder pattern and then covert to Json using GsonBuilder like

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
public class JsonConvertor() {
public static JsonObject convertToJsonObject(Object payload) {
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
return (JsonObject) builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.Policy).
            create().toJsonTree(payload);
}}
```

If I need to remove a required field I use, JsonObj.remove("key") on Json Object created by above function.

Comment: `accounts` is an object itself so your `jsonObj` should point to that object. Besides that please consider adding more information to your question since we can't know what `jsonObj` actually is (actual type, which library, what does it point to etc.) The more effort you put into the question the more people will be willing to help.

Comment: do you have a Java Object that matchs with this JSON?

Comment: yes @melli-182,  i have java object matching with the JSON.

Comment: @Thomas I've added some more information to the question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If Gson is like Jackson (I assume so) you'll have to first get the `JsonObject` "accounts" from the root object and then remove the member "email", e.g. like this:

```
jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("accounts").remove("email");
```

Alternatively - and probably the preferred way - you would map the json object to a POJO (one that has the fields "status", "accounts" and "accounts" would point to another POJO), navigate to the accounts-POJO and set "email" to null there. Then you reformat the root POJO to JSON and apply a setting that omits fields with null values.

**Edit** (answer to the question in the comment):

To make it short, I don't know whether there is a built-in functionality or not but it should be doable.

The problem is that if you just provide keys like `email` etc. you might get situations where there are multiple keys so identifying the correct one could be hard. Thus it might be better to provide the key as `accounts.email` and split the "key" into sub-expressions and then traverse the Json tree using the parts or convert the Json to a POJO and use some expression language (e.g. Java EL or OGNL) to traverse the POJO.

If you want to remove all properties named `email` you could just travers the entire json tree, check whether there is a property with that name and if so remove it.

Comment: `jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("accounts").remove("email");` is working perfectly. Thanks @Thomas. Another related question is there any better way to identify the key that wants to be remove is a key inside main Json object (like 'status') or inside a json object of main json object (like 'email')

Comment: @AnoopPhilip I'll add an edit as it is too much for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use below:

```
DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(json);
doc.delete(jsonPath);
```

Where `json` and and `jsonPath` are strings.

Library: [com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext](http://static.javadoc.io/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/com/jayway/jsonpath/DocumentContext.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.json.JSONObject

// define/initialize jsonObj
jsonObj.remove("field_key")
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to remove json key/value pair is to use `delete` function (in JavaScript).

```js
delete jsonObject.key1.subKey1;
```

Test data:

```js
var jsonObject = {
    key1: {
    subKey1: 'someText',
    subKey2: 'someText'
  },
  key2: 'anotherText'
};

console.log(jsonObject);

delete jsonObject.key1.subKey1;
delete jsonObject.key2;


console.log(jsonObject);
```