# Remove nested key from a json object using java

Tags: java, json

I have the following json structure

```
{  
   "MerchHierarchyEBM":{  
      "DataArea":{  
         "Division":{  
            "UpdatedBy":"SN",
            "Group":{  
               "GroupName":"Womens Fashion*",
               "UpdatedBy":"Data Migration",
               "UpdatedOn":"22-NOV-17",
               "GroupID":"200"
            },
            "DivisionName":"Fashion",
            "UpdatedOn":"22-NOV-17",
            "DivisionID":"2000"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and i want to remove the `"Group"` key and value from the json object using java
i tried few things but didn't work following is my code .

```
JSONObject jsonObjIncomingDatanew =new JSONObject(Result);
jsonObjIncomingDatanew.remove("MerchHierarchyEBM.DataArea.Division.Group");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove key from a Json inside a JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092346/remove-key-from-a-json-inside-a-jsonobject)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Result);
jsonObject
  .getJSONObject("MerchHierarchyEBM")
  .getJSONObject("DataArea")
  .getJSONObject("Division")
  .remove("Group");
```

Or if `getJSONObject()` doesn't work, replace it with `getAsJsonObject()`.