# How can i remove an element or attribute from a json output while parsing from xml, using java

Tags: java, json, xml

```
{"users": {
    "report": {
        "sub": "eng",
        "score": 30
    },
    "user": {
        "name": "test1",
        "age": 20
    }
}}
```

my code is:

package project.example;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Xml2Json {

```
private static final int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
```

system.out.println(jsonObject);

this is the output i got when an xml is parsed to json using java.
now i want to remove age=20 from this output.

Could anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to remove it after you have parsed the xml, or during parsing? In the first case, you can just use some string replacement operator.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Show what you've done so far

Comment: @BartBarnard .. i want to remove it after parsing the xml... i mean after obtaining this json object

Comment: @aeberhart i have  made some changes to my code. Could you please go through this?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Made changes to the code

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319808/remove-nested-key-from-a-json-object-using-java

Comment: @VikasDubey   i tried this code.   change
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("name")
    .getJSONObject("age")
    .remove("user");                                                                                                  but it doest wrk

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.remove(map, oldKey, newKey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use XSLT, this would work as well:

```
String xmlString =
        "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("age");
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Reading your last comment. you had it almost right. Just the order was wrong. You're traversing the JSON tree from the top.

Answer (score 3):

Consider preprocessing the XML using XSLT, or post-processing the JSON similarly.

With XSLT 3.0 you can combine the structural transformation and XML-to-JSON conversion into a single operation.

For example (assuming that the structure of your XML is fixed, and only the values vary):

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="json"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:sequence select='
  map{"users": map {
    "report": map {
        "sub": string(/users/report/@sub),
        "score": string(/users/report/@score)
    },
    "user": map {
        "name": string(/users/user/@name)
    }
  }}'/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The advantage of this approach over use of a standard conversion utility like `XML.toJSONObject` is that you have total control over the JSON that is generated.

Comment: .. i have no previous experience with this.. i didnt get what u say.. could u pls explain.. thank you anyway..

Comment: ..Thank you so much.. But i have to use xml only.. So thats why i cant proceed this way

Comment: Fine. Processing XML without using XSLT is a bit like baking cakes without an oven, but if that's what your company requires of you, then good luck.