# How to remove specific collections from a JSON with Gson in Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I want to remove attributes that I specify collections using Gson.

**My code:**

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = parentActivity.getSharedPreferences(Accommodation.UPLOAD_ACCOMMODATION_DETAILS_ALL, MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Get saved string data in it.
        String userInfoListJsonString = sharedPreferences.getString(Accommodation.UPLOAD_ACCOMMODATION_DETAILS, "");

        // Create Gson object and translate the json string to related java object array.
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Accommodation userInfoDtoArray = gson.fromJson(userInfoListJsonString, Accommodation.class);

        // Loop the UserInfoDTO array and print each UserInfoDTO data in android monitor as debug log.
        // Get each user info in dto.
        Accommodation userInfoDto = userInfoDtoArray;
```

**I printed Json and it have this:**

> {"accommodationName1":"Green Flat",
>   "accommodationName2":"Bangolor",
>   "accommodationName3":"GHost house",
>   "imgAccommodation1":"/data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/cache/cropped6900224487159235524.jpg",
>   "imgAccommodation2":"/data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/cache/cropped3411178797945328810.jpg",
>   "imgAccommodation3":"/data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/cache/cropped9128365945226539316.jpg"}

**I can use this code to get the value:**

```
userInfoDto.accommodationName1;
```

**It show the value :**

> Green Flat

So how I can remove the specific collection of that value?

Comment: this link might be can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092346/remove-key-from-a-json-inside-a-jsonobject

Comment: You may retrieve that JSON from Preference, once the object is retrieved, set its attribute to null, then put the object back to preference.

Comment: @Geros I also been think about that haha, that hacky way. But still have the properly way to remove the value?