# How to generate and walk a parse tree?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I need to parse a quite complex JSON dump of a certain Reddit thread. Obviously, the structure is nested in multiple levels since it describes posts, comments, comments on comments and so on.

As I only need a tiny subset of data from the JSON file, I consider modeling the structure of the JSON file with Java classes (like you would do usually) kind of overkill. Also, the file is simply not very easy to understand, let alone to model.

What I need: the content of each post with reference to its creator. Namely, the "body" and "author" attribute which are hierarchically always on one level.

I was thinking about creating a parse tree and walking it from left to right. If the current node is an attribute with the name "body" or "author", store them in a Post() object and put the object into a global list. Done.

Do you know of any mechanisms in gson or Jackson which could help me for this task? I simply don't want to spend hours creating models or implementing deserializers for data that I don't need.

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need to complete implementation of the object for gson to parse it. You only need to implement the parts/fields that you need.

Comment: Just answered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53225341/6413377) question. If you know what you are searching for you might easily apply my answer to your needs

Comment: @PhaseRush Yeah I know, the fields itself are not the problem. It's more about the hierarchy among the entities. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: @pirho Thank you, that could be interesting! I'll give it a try tomorrow.