# How to remove any type of Key from JSON

Tags: java, json

This is part of my JSON:

```
{
"expressions": {
    "storyId": "doesNotMatter"
},
"facts": { }
}
```

I wish to remove the key 'storyId' from my JSON. How can I do it by converting my JSON into a string and using Regex?

After removing the undesired text my JSON should like like this:

```
{
"expressions": {       
},
"facts": { }
}
```

Note: I don't see my original JSON and can't know who or what the wrapper element is.

Comment: delete obj["expressions"]["storyId"];

Comment: Can you provide clear JSON representation of your actual input and how you are expecting to output

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092346/remove-key-from-a-json-inside-a-jsonobject .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using regex for such thing, the better choice would be using a library for parsing json, remove the value, and then turn it into a string again.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("expressions").remove("storyId");
    String output = jsonObject.toString();
```

if you really want to use regex, you can use the follow

```
    jsonString.replaceAll("(\\\"storyId\\\"|\\'storyId\\')\\s*:\\s*(\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\"|'[^\\\"]*')\\s*,?", "");
```

but just make sure that storyId is really a string, otherwise this regex won't work.

edit: updated my answer, if you want a function that get the parameter to remove with regex,

```
void replaceAllKeys(String keyName, String jsonAsString) {
    String pattern = String.format("(\\\"%s\\\"|\\'%s\\')\\s*:\\s*(\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\"|'[^\\\"]*')\\s*,?", keyName, keyName);
    return jsonAsString.replaceAll(pattern, "");
}
```

Comment: The StoryId is a paramter coming to your method. How the regex should look like in these case?

Comment: updated my answer, i didn't tired it, but i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

First i am assuming you will get all json object in `jsonObj` and then call `remove()` by passing your json key like following:

```
jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("expressions").remove("storyId");
```