# REST assured - compare two JSON objects

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing

Suppose the GET request returns me some JSON object:

```
{
 "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "date": "current_date"
}
```

And I have in my hand a similar object, which I'd like to check it's identical for the the keys "a", "b", "c" and ignore the "date" key.

How can I do that?

Comment: Compare it using a method's object  in which you pass the other object without checking `date` field.

Comment: What do you mean by "using a method's object"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) and it really helps

```
String json1 = "{\r\n" + "  \"a\": 1,\r\n" + "  \"b\": 2,\r\n" + "  \"c\": 3,\r\n"
            + " \"date\": \"30-07-2020\"\r\n" + "}";

String json2 = "{\r\n" + "  \"a\": 1,\r\n" + "  \"b\": 2,\r\n" + "  \"c\": 3,\r\n"
            + " \"date\": \"31-07-2020\"\r\n" + "}";

assertThatJson(json1).whenIgnoringPaths("date").isEqualTo(json2);
```

**Static Import :**

```
import static net.javacrumbs.jsonunit.assertj.JsonAssertions.assertThatJson;
```

**Dependency :**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-unit-assertj</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You will have to add `json.org` or `Jackson 1.x` or `Jackson 2.x` or `Johnzon` or `Gson` to the classpath as well

I use [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it to the Json object and delete the unwanted key. Follow the link for details: [Remove key from a Json inside a JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092346/remove-key-from-a-json-inside-a-jsonobject)

Comment: and then what? How to I compare the two objects?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that rest-assured has some interesting functionalities.

You could do:

```
@Test
public void test() {
   get("/xxxx").then().statusCode(200).assertThat()
  .body("a", equalTo(1)); 
}
```

More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the JSON into a JS object, then compare each property of that  object if that property has a key not equal to "date"

In the code below is comparing `obj1` to `obj2` and ignoring the `date` property.
It prints "identical" if they are both the same and "not identical" if they are not (ignoring the `date` property)

```js
var obj1 = JSON.parse ('{ "a":"1","b":"2", "c":"3", "date":"current_date"}' );

var obj2 = JSON.parse ('{ "a":"1","b":"2", "c":"3", "date":"another_date"}' );

let s1 = Object.keys(obj1).length; // length of obj1
let s2 = Object.keys(obj2).length; // length of obj2

let identical = true ;

for ( let i = 0 ; i < s1 ; i ++ ){
  if (i >= s2) {
    identical = false ;
    break ;
  }
  
  let current_key = Object.keys(obj1)[i];
  let current_value = obj1[current_key];
  
  if (current_key.localeCompare("date") != 0){
     if (current_value.localeCompare(obj2[current_key]) != 0){
       identical = false ;
       break;
     }
  }
 
}

if (identical){
  console.log ("Identical");
}else {
  console.log ("Not identical");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [AssertJ ignoring fields in the comparison](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-fields)
   For than it's needed to deserialize json from response (for Spring Test: `MvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString()`) to Object.
   It is possible to deserialize json response with [REST Assured Content-Type based Deserialization](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#content-type-based-deserialization)
2. Use unstrict compare with [JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert).
   In order to not creating json by hand, it is possible serialize expected object with Jackson `ObjectMapper`. For fields exclusion:

```
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
map.remove(...);
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)
```