# How to drop key in JsonObject

Tags: java, json

How to remove a Json key. I looked for some examples on the portal itself, but none solved what I need.

i need to eliminate a json property, is it possible to do? It is like?

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
    public JsonObject getData() {               
            JsonObject jsonObj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("instanceType", "XXXXX")
                .build();       
            return jsonObj;
        }

the json output is like this:

    {
        "instanceType": {
            "chars": "XXXXX",
            "string": "XXXXX",
            "valueType": "STRING"
        }
    }
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
{
    "instanceType": {
        "string": "XXXXXX",
        "valueType": "STRING"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Gson tag on your question correct? Gson does not have a `createObjectBuilder()` method.

Comment: Good observation, I removed the tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove key from a Json inside a JsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092346/remove-key-from-a-json-inside-a-jsonobject)